# Convert Numeric to String in Java (poi)

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to read cells in Excel using poi-4.1.2 in Java. It seems as they canceled Cell.setCellType() method, and I cannot understand how should I read (as a String) numeric type of values.

One can see here:
https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html

It says: "setCellType(CellType cellType)
Deprecated.
This method is deprecated and will be removed in POI 5.0. Use explicit setCellFormula(String), setCellValue(...) or setBlank() to get the desired result."

But neither of those help me. I don't see the point to blank my value, and not set the value nor set the cell formula.

Can anybody helps me? thanks!

Edit: I've already tried to use cell.getCellValue.toString()...

Comment: and what was wrong with your approach?

Comment: i get "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a STRING value from a NUMERIC cell"

Comment: What does String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue()) do?

Comment: What's wrong with using `DataFormatter` as per the docs?